# PrototypeJS: Selecting visible elements

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

I am trying to formulate a selector to select a set of visible elements. Our application uses the Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.6.0.3.

The markup I'm working with is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li style="display:none;">1 Hidden</li>
    <li style="display:none;">2 Hidden</li>
    <li style="">3 Visible</li>
    <li style="display:none;">4 Hidden</li>
    <li style="display:none;">5 Hidden</li>
    <li style="display:none;">6 Hidden</li>
    <li>7 Visible</li>
    <li style="">8 Visible</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, some elements *may* have a style attribute, but only the hidden ones contain the string "display:none;". I need to select the `<li>` elements that are visible, where visibility is defined as "does not contain display:none".

What I've tried to far:

```
var visibleItems = $$('li[style*="display:none"]'); // Yields: [ ]
var visibleItems = $$('li[style*="display"]'); // Yields: [li, li, li, li, li], but isn't specific enough
```

Ideas? Ideally I'd like this to be as compact as possible, but I'll take what I can get.

Yes, I know that [jQuery can do this](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) but I do not want to introduce another framework in to this application since much of it already depends on Prototype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can filter the items using the [findAll](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/findAll) function:

```
var notVisible = $$('li').findAll(function(el) { return !el.visible(); });
```

Comment: I have the same question, and this answer will not work if the elements were hidden by CSS. In that case the function returns them as visible. I'm still looking for and answer...