# PrototypeJS: Selecting the odd subset of visible children

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

This is related to my [previous question about selecting visible elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796273/prototypejs-selecting-visible-elements). Now, here's the twist: Let's say I want to select the odd children only from the set of visible children of an element. What would be the best way to do this?

Edit: here is an example of my input and expected output.

```
<!-- A list with some visible and invisible children -->
<ul class="stripe">
    <li>Visible 1</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Visible 2</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Visible 3</li>
    <li>Visible 4</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Visible 5</li>
    <li>Visible 6</li>
    <li>Visible 7</li>
</ul>

<!-- Only the visible children. -->
<li>Visible 1</li>
<li>Visible 4</li>
<li>Visible 6</li>
<li>Visible 7</li>

<!-- The "odd" visible children. -->
<li>Visible 1</li>
<li>Visible 6</li>
```

I came up with two ways. One works, but the other doesn't.

```
// Method one: Returns the odd children whether they are visible or not. :(
var listChildren = $$("ul.stripe > li");
var oddChildren = allChildren
  .findAll(function(el) { return el.visible(); })
    .findAll(function(el) { return el.match("li:nth-child(odd)"); });
oddChildren.invoke("addClassName", "odd");
```

What I am currently doing now is the following:

```
// Method two: grouping!
var listChildren = $$("ul.stripe > li");
var oddChildren = listChildren
  .findAll(function(el) { return el.visible(); })
    .eachSlice(2, function(el) {
      el[0].addClassName("odd");    
    });
```

This code seems like it could be improved. Can anyone suggest a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS select won't work for the application you desire, it doesn't work correctly on an Array outside of the context of the DOM.

You can do this as follows:

```
var index = 0;
var myChildren = $$("ul.stripe > li")
    .select(function(e) { return e.visible(); })
    .select(function(e) {return ++index % 2 == 1; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you merge the two conditions like this?

```
var listChildren = $$("ul.stripe > li");
var oddChildren = allChildren
  .findAll(function(el) { return el.visible() && el.match("li:nth-child(odd)"); })
oddChildren.invoke("addClassName", "odd");
```

Comment: Yes. However, the problem is that I want to select the visible elements first, and then from *those* select the "odd" elements. The problem with this (any with my chained findAll version) is that the elements "oddness" is being tested outside of that "visible" subset of children.